# Vue | Problems with vue-moment.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs

I'm having a problem wrapping my head around the implementation of vue-moment or moment.js inside a .vue file. So I would like to have a date inside the vue method that I can then manipulate to find a time span between a past time and a current time and update it live. All the googling has pointed me towards moment.js

My main.js file has it implemented with

```
import VueMoment from 'vue-moment';

Vue.use(VueMoment);
```

I'm then trying to access the method inside the template like this

```
<p>{{ moment(1481889223).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') }}</p>
```

Is there something inherent that i'm doing incorrectly. I just cannon't seem to get the moment to output a date/time

Also if this isn't the solution is there another easy way to access date time in a .vue file?

Comment: did you try `<p>{{ 1481889223 | moment('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') }}</p>`

Comment: Nope. That worked perfectly thanks!

Comment: @Derek Pollard, consider to write it as an answer so people in the future can find it.

Comment: @SølveTornøe you're right - posted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what we are missing here is that `vue-moment` introduces moment as a [*filter* function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html).

From the [usage documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-moment#usage):

> Simply set moment as the filtering function and you're good to go. At least one argument is expected, which the filter assumes to be a format string if the argument doesn't match any of the other filtering methods.

So knowing this, we can pass the date (as long as it is properly formatted) accordingly:

```
<span>{{ someDate | moment("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY") }}</span>
```

More specific to the original post:

```
<p>{{ 1481889223 | moment('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') }}</p>
```